# Bigquery csv download date not showing correctly

Tags: google-bigquery

I completed a query with one column in date format. When I downloaded the csv file, I cannot configure date to the correct format. It either shows up as a scientific number or ####### if I choose short date format. How can I get the dates show up correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery outputs writes timestamps as epoch time when exporting as CSV. I assume you're opening your CSV in Excel, which doesn't handle epoch time very well.

Try modifying your query to use The DATE() function which outputs your date as a string "YYYY-MM-DD". E.g.

```
SELECT DATE(date_column) FROM mydata.mytable LIMIT 100
```

Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions)